# Android library projects libs dependencies

Tags: android, library-project, android-support-library

I'm currently working on a project where I use multiple libraries. Multiple libraries use the android support library, so when I want to compile my app Eclipse complains about it with a Dalvik error. I already found out that I should only have the support library 1 time in my project. But, this breaks the library projects which causes that I cannot compile anymore.

How should I properly handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use support library such as v4 and your project contains other library projects, you should keep the only one version of the v4 library. Choose one of the library file (the one that has the biggest size for example), remove all the duplicates and then copy this v4 into each project library which uses it.

Comment: You mean copy the support-v4.jar file into each project's /libs folder?  Wouldn't Dalvik complain of jar conflicts if you have the same jar in multiple places?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your libraries include the support library already. Maybe it's failing because it's already included.

Comment: That's the whole point, they do include it. But how can I fix this problem without removing them? Cause if I remove the support library, my library project doesn't compile anymore, and I cannot compile my main app anymore.